# Consuming MySql Procedure out parameter which contains @ in node js

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm having issues with consuming Out Parameters from mySql in node JS when they contain @, I've searched for similar question but can't see any answers to my specific question:

Here's the procedure (not my code)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `getuser`(IN `p_googleemail` varchar(64), 
out `p_userjson` json) 
SET @'p_userJSON' = 
( 
       SELECT json_object('email', USER.email, 'lastName', USER.lastname, 'firstName', USER.firstname )
       FROM   test.USER 
       WHERE  email = p_googleemail); 
select @p_userJSON; 

end
```

Here is a snippet of my Node Code:

```
/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
          getConnection(function(err, con) {
            googleEmail ='test@gmail.com';
            que = 'CALL test.getUser(?, @p_userJSON);';
            con.query(que,[googleEmail], function(err, results) {
                if (err) throw err;
                con.release();
                res.send(results);
            });
        });


});
```

This is the response:

```
[
    [{
        "@p_userJSON": "{\"email\": \"test@gmail.com\",  \"lastName\": \"test\", \"firstName\": \"test\"}"
    }],
    {
        "fieldCount": 0,
        "affectedRows": 0,
        "insertId": 0,
        "serverStatus": 34,
        "warningCount": 1,
        "message": "",
        "protocol41": true,
        "changedRows": 0
    }
]
```

How do I return the results from @p_userJSON as part of my rest service? I understand I'll have to unescape the json from the out param but I can't even return the @p_userJSON value.

Many thanks!

**Edit:**

My hack to get around the issue for the minute, this not the full code as got some error handling if there are no results (probably a better way but I've only been using js for a few weeks)

```
var datapackstr = JSON.stringify(results[0]);
var datapack = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(datapackstr.substring((datapackstr.lastIndexOf('@p_userJSON') + 12) + 1).slice(0, -2)));
```

Comment: You'll probably have to `JSON.parse` that value to get a proper structure back.

Comment: I've had to hack it for the time being but surely there must be a better way

Comment: A less hack version is to use an abstraction layer like [Sequelize](http://sequelizejs.com).

Comment: You'll also want to use `VARCHAR(255)` as a default string field. Email addresses can and will be longer than 64 characters. Technically the limit is 320 characters, but in practice 255 is a safe default.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this thread is 6 years old I came across basically the same issue with the @. The problem is with the JSON string that's being returned and JSON.parse's ability to deal with the stirngs in @p_userJSON.

The below JSON string works as expected.

```js
var result = '[[{"@p_userJSON": "{\\\"email\\\": \\\"test@gmail.com\\\",  \\\"lastName\\\": \\\"test\\\", \\\"firstName\\\": \\\"test\\\"}"}],{"fieldCount": 0,"affectedRows": 0,"insertId": 0,"serverStatus": 34,"warningCount": 1,"message": "","protocol41": true,"changedRows": 0}]';
var res = JSON.parse(result);

console.log(res[0][0]['@p_userJSON']);
```

You can see a working example in a node fiddle [here](https://runkit.com/embed/urgw80pg19yr).

I did need to make some manual changes to the JSON. Remember that JSON.parse won't throw an error when it fails to return an actual JSON object it will simply return an object for each character in the input string.

You can find more info about the JSON.parse function [here](http://www.developerknowhow.com/2268/escaping-json-in-javascript).